# How do you determine midi file duration (in bars) in NAudio 1.7?

Tags: midi, naudio, duration

I am trying to figure out the duration of a sequence of midi notes in a *.MID file using NAudio 1.7.  The midi file I'm using reports "EndTrack" at 1507 which is the time of the last NoteOff.  I would have expected the value to be 1536 which is the duration of a 4-bar phrase.

Where else would this information be represented or how do I calculate it?

Comment: Look at the post ***[here](http://mark-dot-net.blogspot.com/2014/09/creating-rf64-and-bwf-wav-files-with.html)***.  It may have a technique that is useful for getting duration or size in bytes, etc.

Comment: A *.mid file is not like a wave file ... the midi file simply contains a series of midi events, note on, note off, etc.  The number events has nothing to do with the duration the midi represents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `EndTrack` event is a separate event that can have its own time.

If the MIDI file does not bother to align the end to a measure, then that's what you get.

If you want to count the number of measures in the file (which might not make sense for all files), you have to round up the last tick value yourself.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that.  I have test mid file that represents a 32-bar phrase with a single note starting at bar 2 for 1 bar.  The Start tick is 384 (4 quarter notes * 96 ticks per quarter), it's length is also 384 ticks, but nothing says the midi file represents 12288 ticks (32 bars x 4 quarters x 96 ticks per quarter), and there appears to be no way to derive that.  The EndTrack event says the track ends after the 2nd bar.

Comment: Where do you get the 32 bars from? If the `EndTrack` is after the 2nd bar, then that is the length of the file.

Comment: Hmmm, my bad ... I always assumed that if I created a 32-bar phrase and exported it, I'd get a 32-bar phrase back (tested in Reaper and Live) ... looks like I'm in error.  Sorry about that.

Comment: @CL. do you know of any document explaining in detail how note value is represented in MIDI format?

Comment: @nightcod3r To ask a question, use the "Ask Question" button.

Comment: @CL. taken from the banner that shows when you place the pointer on the "add a comment" label: "Use comments to ask for more information..."

Comment: @nightcod3r ... about the answer itself. Your question is unrelated.